# Guideline: field is not valid

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextview

I added the check text in textview.

If the text is empty I can:

- add red border
- show message
- add exclamation mark
- ...

  if (textView.text == nil)
  {
      ...
  }

But I didn't find answer in guidelines. What should I do if the text is empty?

http://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-views/text-views

Comment: you can also try textView.text.length == 0 instead of textView.text == nil

Comment: I think you are asking, "Does Apple recommend how to indicate to the user that a text field is required?" Apple does not make such specific recommendations. [This is all they say.](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/interaction/data-entry/) However you can try asking this question at [UX StackExchange.](http://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=required+field+ios)